# How to make Zsh not store failed command

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

#### Problem

I'm using oh-my-zsh and Antigen to manage my Zsh.

Sometimes I will accidentally enter a wrong/failed command into Zsh and it is very annoying when the [zsh-autosuggestions plugin](https://github.com/tarruda/zsh-autosuggestions) throws up these commands.

For e.g., say I typed
`gut status` rather than `git status`.

Now, as I attempt to type the correct command again, once I typed `g`, the autosuggestion plugin will throw up `gut status` as that is the closest match in recent history. But that is a failed command!

What I **want to do is to keep these failed commands from "polluting" my history** so the autosuggestion plugin will not suggest them.

#### What I have done

I've searched for this and the closest match to keeping out entries from the history are that of setting HIST_IGNORE_SPACE, or methods to ignore specific commands, or to delete commands manually after entering them. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/is-there-any-way-to-keep-a-command-from-being-added-to-your-history) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48305/how-can-i-run-a-command-in-zsh-without-pushing-it-onto-the-current-sessions-his). But as @Adaephon 52 noted, this takes place *after* the deed is done.

#### What I'm considering doing

What I have in mind right now is to write a function that gets triggered every time a failed command is entered into Zsh to delete the latest entry from history. However, I'm not familiar enough with Zsh to know whether this sort of trigger exists or how to go about doing it.

---

#### Note on the accepted solution

For those who are interested in this problem, the accepted solution works in the sense that failed commands are not stored in the history file. `fc -l` or `history` confirms this.

However, it seems that the zsh-autosuggestions plugin is doing its own *local* caching of sorts (or is generating suggestions using other mechanism), so it will still suggest the failed commands, but *only if the session is not over*. When the user starts a new instance of the shell, when presumably the plugin has to load the cached history, it no longer suggests the failed commands (unless you enter them again, of course).

The proposed solution is technically correct as I (mistakenly) framed my question in such a way that it only requires an answer that stops Zsh from storing the failed commands and the accepted solution does that (albeit in a limited way; See link in solution for details).

Anyone who is familiar with shell scripting (I'm not) and motivated enough  can check the [zsh-autosuggestions script](https://github.com/tarruda/zsh-autosuggestions/blob/master/autosuggestions.zsh).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[*Bart Schaefer* proposed the following approach](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users//2014/msg00715.html) to the same question on the *zsh users* mailing list:

```
 zshaddhistory() { whence ${${(z)1}[1]} >| /dev/null || return 1 }
```

This function is executed before the command line is written to history. If it does return 1, the current command line is neither appended to the history file nor to the local history stack. However, the check if the command will trigger a *command not found* error covers only simple cases. E.g. this line will be on the history:

```
echo foo; echooo bar
```

But it works fine for your example

```
gut status
```

Please be aware, that the wrong command will show up upon `UP-ARROW` (so that you can correct it!), but is not in the history stack; check with `fc -l`.

---

One possible extension of this basic function is to account for setting environment variables in the command line, e.g. like `DEBUG=1 ./some_prog`. Here the functions checks if a word on the command line contains an equal sign and if so checks the next word for a valid command:

```
 zshaddhistory() {
   local j=1
   while ([[ ${${(z)1}[$j]} == *=* ]]) {
     ((j++))
   }
   whence ${${(z)1}[$j]} >| /dev/null || return 1
 }
```

Comment: This does stops the caching of failed commands. But it seems that the zsh-autosuggestions plugin is doing its own *local* caching of recent entries so it still throws up these suggestions as long as the session is not over. Once I open a new shell, when presumably it has to load the cached history, it no longer suggests them. This solved part of the problem and I guess I have to check with the zsh-autosuggestions plugin's maintainer to resolve the remaining issue. Still, thanks!

Comment: where do you put this function?

Comment: @Daniel: In any config file _zsh_ will read upon startup, typically your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: I tried with an alias instead of command (z-shell), a failed with alias still apear in zsh history. @mpy

Comment: # zshaddhistory is a zsh hook fn meaning it is triggered by an event or action
# in this case, when a history line has been read interactively, but before it is executed
# whence is like cmd which or where
# ${(z)string_parameter} will take the string_parameter and break it up at spaces and return an array of strings

Comment: # 1 is the cmd that was read interactively
# [1] is indexing array returned by ${(z)1}
# returng 1 tells zsh not to save 1, the cmd line that was read 
# > means overwrite, |> means overwrite ignoring noclobber setting

Comment: A con with this solution is that commands started with setting some environment variables also will not be saved to the history even if the command is successful.

E.g.
`$ DEBUG=1 ./some_prog`

would not be saved due to the preceding env var.

Comment: @Erikw: This is correct, but one can always tailor the given example function to different  requirements; see edited answer.

Comment: @mpy the modified function allowing preceding env vars seems to work great on the first few tries. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `fc` command supports editing your history. In case you mistyped e.g. the previous command you can enter the following:

```
$ fc -e nano -1
```

*You can replace `nano` with the command of your preferred editor. Also you can set the `EDITOR` variable (parameter) in your zsh config. ([See referring SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299610/zsh-command-not-found-for-editor))*

You need to save the file (the one, created in a system temp. folder, by fc). After it you will end up with the line(s) edited. `Enter` will run it or you can press `Ctrl+C` to finish your editing.

For further details see zsh documentation: [Zsh: editing history](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-editing-history)

---

## In case you want to edit the entire history

```
$ fc -W; nano "$HISTFILE"; fc -R
```

*...again replace nano if you wish*

It simply writes out the history -including the cache- then opens the file with an editor.

Please note that **zsh** knows three types of history:

- **Internal**: commands you entered since log-in
- **Local**: the one available within the active shell - [HISTFILE + Internal]
- **"Global"**: it depens but let say it's the file set in HISTFILE

*Please bear in mind that in case your history file is shared ([`SHARE_HISTORY`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Description-of-Options)) and you have more than one zsh shell opened with the user in question then you better run the `fc -W` command in those shells first. Once you finished with the edit then run `fc -R`. Otherwise the commands entered within those shells won't be stored and then recognized your manual edit of the `HISTFILE`.*

Comment: The question says that the OP has found ‘‘methods … to delete commands manually after entering them.’’, and asks for a way to do this automatically when a command fails with ‘‘command not found’’ or some other error.

Answer (score -2):

not sure how omz runs it  but in both bash and regular zsh  prefixing with a space  keeps it out of  .history and henceforth also out of auto complete/suggest

i.e.

```
<space>ll -ahZ  /home/%USER
```

Comment: The OP wants to keep wrong/failed commands from the history. And as he only knows that the command was wrong *after* running it, adding a space *before* running it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Adaephon Exactly. I know that it is possible to have ZSH ignore commands starting with spaces. Perhaps I should have mentioned this in my post.

Comment: personally  i don't keep any history (by doing this )   another solution --- get off the crappily  maintained Oh-my-zsh  for pure  zsh or  prestzo (more more well maintained and sane up to date configurations...  this  lack of functionality has been in the "issues" for some time